# Chrome extension authorize in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement user authorization for chrome extension.

I want to open new tab, log in there and receive access token and next get back to extension tab to update options page (show user is logged).
I use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow but it opens new window instead of tab as I'd like to. 
I want to achieve login similar like in Pocket extension.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you will need to forgo using the `chrome.identity` API. There is no such option.

Instead, you'll have to do magic with content scripts to extract the resulting token, and you might have some problems with regards to callback URL - you can no longer use the one provided by the `identity` API.